# Transferring my jquery code from a w3school editor to my wordpress site

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have a problem about transferring a Jquery Code from w3schools to my Wordpress site. Actually it's working properly in w3schools but when I try to transfer it on my wordpress site the output appears for just about a millisecond.

Any help are highly appreciated! Thank You!

Here's my code by the way:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#topbar").toggle(function(){
    $(this).animate({height:200},200);
  }, 
  function(){
    $(this).animate({height:40},200);
  });
});
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#topsbar").toggle(function(){
    $(this).animate({height:100},200);
  }, 
  function(){
    $(this).animate({height:40},200);
  });
});
</script>

<style type="text/css">
#topbar { width: 100%; height: 40px; background-color: #000; color: #FFF;overflow:hidden;}
#topsbar { width: 100%; height: 40px; background-color: #000; color: #FFF;overflow:hidden;}
</style>


<div id="topbar"> Table<br/>
<br/>
<table width=100% border=1>
<tr align=center>
<td>Time</td>
<td>Time</td>
<td>Time</td>
</tr>
<tr align=center>
<td>Date</td>
<td>Date</td>
<td>Date</td>
</tr>
<tr align=center>
<td>Age</td>
<td>Age</td>
<td>Age</td>
</tr>
<tr align=center>
<td>Place</td>
<td>Place</td>
<td>Place</td>
</tr>
</table></div>
<br/>
<div id="topsbar"> Table </div>
```

Comment: what do you want exactly?

Comment: I just want it to work properly in my wordpress site. The problem is that when I tried transferring my code that I edited from the w3school editor into my wordpress the output seems not working properly.

Comment: than provide w3school link too.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_transition1

Comment: i cant find any hover event written in your code. Do you want hover effect?

Comment: Yes but my hover is clickable when I click the div just expands its height. What should I do ?

Comment: it is expanding on click. I tried your code...

Comment: Yes then do you have any idea on how this could should work on my wordpress site ?

Comment: works well with jquery 1.9.1.  check http://jsfiddle.net/we6uW/

Answer (score 0):

your markup above is missing the html, head ,body, and meta tag

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>

    <style type="text/css">
    #topbar {
        width: 100%;
        height: 40px;
        background-color: #000;
        color: #FFF;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    #topsbar {
        width: 100%;
        height: 40px;
        background-color: #000;
        color: #FFF;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    </style>

    </head>
    <body>

    <div id="topbar"> Table<br/>
        <br/>
        <table width=100% border=1>
            <tr align=center>
                <td>Time</td>
                <td>Time</td>
                <td>Time</td>
            </tr>
            <tr align=center>
                <td>Date</td>
                <td>Date</td>
                <td>Date</td>
            </tr>
            <tr align=center>
                <td>Age</td>
                <td>Age</td>
                <td>Age</td>
            </tr>
            <tr align=center>
                <td>Place</td>
                <td>Place</td>
                <td>Place</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div id="topsbar"> Table </div>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

      $("#topbar").toggle(function(){
        $(this).animate({height:200},200);
        }, 
        function(){
        $(this).animate({height:40},200);
      });

      $("#topsbar").toggle(function(){
        $(this).animate({height:100},200);
        }, 
        function(){
        $(this).animate({height:40},200);
      });

    }); // end ready()
    </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

also you just need to have one jQuery ready() handler since you only have 2 toggle() methods that should go inside it

I cant see your WordPress site, but you would take the script tags and add them to WordPress using the WordPress **[wp_enqueue_script()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script)** methods

**http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script**

and then add the styles CSS to your WordPress Theme **style.css**